# Coskewness: three or two random variables?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, skewness, moments

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coskewness) for coskewness says

> coskewness is a measure of how much three random variables change
> together

It then says

> If two random variables exhibit positive coskewness they will tend to
> undergo extreme positive deviations at the same time. Similarly, if
> two random variables exhibit negative coskewness they will tend to
> undergo extreme negative deviations at the same time.

Why is the definition for three random variables, yet the examples are able to explain it for only two random variables?

Comment: Although that article is badly written, it does consider the "coskewness" of two variables $(X,Y)$ to be $S_{X+Y},$ as its example makes clear.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that, and edited the explanation on wikipedia you quoted, to reflect the three-variable definition used in the rest of the article. Though, looking around online, many people seem to be using "coskewness" to refer to a property of two random variables. Here's the relationship between the three-variable and two-variable definitions of coskewness: The three-variable definition is the one given on wikipedia: $S(X,Y,Z) = \frac{1}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y\sigma_Z}E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)(Z-\mu_Z)]$, where $\mu_X$ and $\sigma_X$ refer to the mean and standard deviation, respectively, of $X$. The two-variable definition is just the same formula, but using the same variable for two of the inputs (i.e. $S(X,X,Y)$). I have no idea why anyone would want to restrict attention to this two-variable case, but it seems that it is popular to do so. Note that the three-variable definition of coskewness is symmetric between the three variables, but the two-variable definition of coskewness is not symmetric between its two variables, since $S(X,X,Y)\neq S(X,Y,Y)$. So any explanation of the two-variable notion of skewness that treats the two variables interchangably, including the one you quoted from wikipedia, is incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to CV! I believe you've mis-transcribed the equation from wikipedia. It should be $S(X,Y,Z) = \frac{1}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y\sigma_Z}E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)(Z-\mu_Z)]$. Your rendering would always equal zero as  $E[X-\mu_X] = 0$

Comment: Oops, fixed. Thanks for catching that.